# Flash content only shows a quarter of the image when played in full screen on second monitor

Tags: google-chrome, macos, adobe-flash

I have macOS Sierra 10.12 installed, and Google Chrome 54.0.2840.71(64-bit) with Flash Player 23.0.0.205.

I'm using the second monitor to watch movies. When I try to open full-screen Flash Player on the second monitor, I see only the top-left quarter of the image. Everything works like a charm with HTML5 video players.

I tried to install Flash Player from Adobe's site (both NPAPI and PPAPI), but the version is only 23.0.0.185. Moreover, I can't change the version in chrome://plugins as it's not showing there, so I can only enable/disable plugin.

I'm 100% sure everything was OK yesterday, but today something has happened and I can't find out what exactly. Does anybody has same problems? Do you know how to fix it?

Reported bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4197639

Comment: Using Safari 10.0.1(12602.2.14.0.7) and Flash Player 23.0.0.185 I can successfully start full-screen video on the second monitor.
If you're OK with migration to Safari - do it. I'm still looking for some Chrome solution